# angular showing/hiding DOM elements based on what class they have

Tags: css, angular, typescript

I'm going to simplify my problem a bit, because I really want to avoid adding a lot of code, because this is a gigantic project we are working on if I started adding code snippets, there would be a lot of it.

My project has one feature, where you have a list of different div elements in the left column of the page, and they can be individually dragged to the right column, where you can make your own list out of these elements in the order you choose.

These div elements are all the same child component. My task is to add a dropdown to these div elements, but only to the ones that have been dragged to the right column (you can choose additional preferences, once it's in the right column). It shouldn't be there on the divs in the left column.

The only way to differentiate between them is by the class name. The ones on the left have a class="left" and the ones on the right get the class="right".

Now I'm wondering if there's a way where I can write some code to the effect: if the element has the class 'left', hide the dropdown, else show the dropdown?

Comment: How are you dragging and dropping the divs? There must be a layer or component doing this?

Comment: There's the main component, its child component is the area, where the divs are being dropped to, and an item component for the div items being dragged and dropped. But It's a gigantic project and I'm just working on parts of it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, this is definitely possible.

1. Create a Directive that has a `@HostBinding()` for a specific class and just add the directive to every component.
2. Inject `ChildComponent` into the constructor of that Directive. You can also inject `ViewContainerRef` and then call `this.viewContainerRef["_data"].componentView.component` This will give you reference to that child element that the directive is put on.
3. Once the `@HostBinding('.left')` event handler is triggered this will be the function that gets called when the class you're looking for is added. Here you can then access that `ChildComponent` and then presumably call a method on that child component to show/hide the mat-select

I haven't actually tested this but thats the approach I would take.

Comment: I really love this solution. I didn't get the chance to implement it in this project, because my mentor then gave me a different suggestion: in the right-column.component, set up a boolean, which is set to true when an item is dropped in and sends the boolean through the @Input() to the div-item-component.
But I will be using your solution in my own project, since I have a similar conundrum there. It will be a good practice, since I haven't really used @HostBinding yet.

Comment: awesome, I am glad it helped you out. Did that answer your question then?

Comment: Yes, it answered my question :)

Comment: Glad it did. Any chance you can mark it as the accepted answer :) ?

Answer (score 0):

You might also achieve this thru your css. Something like

```
 div[class*="left"] dropdown-element {
     display: none;
        ~or~
     visibility: hidden;
 }
```